# Replicating an object's structure in R, minus any contained data

Tags: r, list, data-structures, dataframe

I would like to have an output structure, which replicates that of the input's.

for example, I have a list of 10 items. Each item itself a list of data frames, which perhaps goes two or three levels deep, e.g.:

```
> my_list

$AA
->NULL
$BB
->NULL
$CC
$CC$test_data
$CC$test_data$x1
$CC$test_data$x1$Adele
   prog1   prog2
1:     1 "Rolling"
2:     2  "in the"
3:     4    "deep"

$CC$test_data$x1$BeeGees
->NULL
$CC$test_data$y1
[1] "cold" "hot"  "warm"
$DD
->NULL
$EE
->NULL
$FF
->NULL
$GG
->NULL
```

I would like the structure, but without all the data actually stored untder the titles.

One could argue that I could copy the list object and just replace the data with the output, but this requires me to store to much data at once, and also I just want to use the empty structure as a template to load in the future without all the data that it contained.

Comment: Can we have a reproducible example

Comment: Hmm, I think `rapply(my_list, function(q) { q <- NULL; q }, how = "list")` might work.

Comment: That seems to have done the trick! I need to test it out a bit more, but it does seem to have reproduced the structure, thanks! If it turns out not to have worked for any reason, I will add a reproducible example to the post.

Comment: @RichardScriven - Do you happen to know of a place to read more about `rapply`? The help page doesn't explain the curley braces part, which I saw in a post (but can't find it now, sorry!) apparently allow greater functionality, that is multiple input parameters. What should I even google?

Comment: The curly braces are part of the inner anonymous function (in the second argument). I discovered that you can just return NULL as well.   `rapply(my_list, function(q) NULL, how = "list")` works too.  I don't really know where you can read more about `rapply()` other than searching for it right here on SO and the help file.